# redireccionar dominio www a sin www gestionado en aws de amazon

Tags: aws, redirección, dominio, subdominio, redireccionamiento

Necesito redireccionar dominio www a sin www que está gestionado en aws de amazon
El https://ejemplo.com funciona bien

Ejemplo: cuando pones https://www.ejemplo.com no redirige a https://ejemplo.com aparece el error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Lo que hice sin buenos resultados:

1- en buckets

- nombre: [www.ejemplo.com](http://www.ejemplo.com)
- dentro del Alojamiento de sitios web estáticos
- Redirigir las solicitudes de un objeto
- Nombre del alojamiento: ejemplo.com

2- en route 53

- nombre: [www.ejemplo.com](http://www.ejemplo.com)
- Tipo: A
- Politica Simple
- Alias: Si
- Valor: ejemplo.com.

Mil gracias!!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: gracias por contestar! el problema es que cuando pongo  https://www.ejemplo.com no redirige a https://ejemplo.com aparece el error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con la [documentación](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53), habría que realizar varios cambios:

El bucket debe identificarse con el dominio de destino, no con el de origen. En tu caso la redirección que esperas es `www.dominio.com -> dominio.com`, luego el bucket debe llamarse **dominio.com**

Por otro lado, el registro de Route53 debe tener **el nombre en blanco**. Lo que debes hacer es crear una *hosted zone* con el valor **[www.dominio.com](http://www.dominio.com)** y dentro de esa zona crear el registro.

Es este registro el que hace realmente la redirección al dominio identificado por S3